# manually load a rdlc report to reportviewer in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

i created a report and trying to load it to a reportviewer manually but not able to get it loaded .
my code

```
 Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
  ReportViewer1.Reset()
    Dim ReportDataSource1 As Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource = New Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource
    ReportDataSource1.Name = "InvoiceData_DataTable1"
    ReportDataSource1.Value = New InvoiceDataTableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter().GetData("EBM267")
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear()
    Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(ReportDataSource1)
    ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "Billmanagement.report.rdlc"
    ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub
```

my Dataset name is InvoiceData
DataTable1 has a parameter billno
which i am supplying for demo but not working please let me know why my report is not loading
a blank report with error is comming 
"A datasource instance has not been supplied for the datasource DataSet1"

Answer (score 0):

In `Billmanagement.report.rdlc` you are using an oject with `.DataSetName` property set as `DataSet1`: check every Table/List/Matrix in your report.